# How can I create a vector in pandas dataframe from other attributes of the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vector, attributes

I have a pandas dataframe like this, and I want to generate another attribute containing the elements of the row in a vector type element. For example:

```
+--------+--------+
|  Atr1  |  Atr2  |
+--------+--------+
|  1     |  A     |
+--------+--------+
|  2     |  B     |
+--------+--------+
|  4     |  C     |
+--------+--------+
```

How can I get this one:

```
+--------+--------+----------+
|  Atr1  |  Atr2  | features |
+--------+--------+----------+
|  1     |  A     | [1, A]   |
+--------+--------+----------+
|  2     |  B     | [2, B]   |
+--------+--------+----------+
|  4     |  C     | [4, C]   |
+--------+--------+----------+
```

Comment: you got these many downvotes, because you didn't make a try. try to solve the problem by yourself, if you got stuck somewhere then raise the question.

Comment: Can I select the attributes that I want to create a list with? For example, if I have atr1, atr2 and atr3, create a list with atr1 and atr2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need:

```
df['features'] = df.values.tolist()

print(df)
   Atr1 Atr2 features
0     1    A   [1, A]
1     2    B   [2, B]
2     4    C   [4, C]
```

If you have multiple columns and want to select particular columns then:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Atr1":[1,2,4],"Atr2":['A','B','C'],"Atr3":['x','y','z']})
print(df)
   Atr1 Atr2 Atr3
0     1    A    x
1     2    B    y
2     4    C    z

#Selecting Atr2 and Atr3 columns
df['features'] = df[['Atr2','Atr3']].values.tolist()
print(df)

   Atr1 Atr2 Atr3 features
0     1    A    x   [A, x]
1     2    B    y   [B, y]
2     4    C    z   [C, z]
```

Comment: Can I select the attributes that I want to create a list with? For example, if I have atr1, atr2 and atr3, create a list with atr1 and atr2?